# Force Python Pandas DataFrame( read_csv() method) to avoid/not consider first row of my csv/txt file as header

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a txt file (data.txt) using pandas read_csv method. The file has 16 columns and 600 rows. However, after reading the csv into dataframe, I observed that first row in my data.txt file has been taken as the column headings in the dataframe. This reduces the size of my dataframe to 599 from 600 in my text file. How can I force pandas to not use first row as headers for Dataframe. 
I am using this code to read the file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\<my_directory_path>\data.txt)
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv("FILE", header=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add header=None:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\<my_directory_path>\data.txt",header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `header=None` to read your data in with integers to index the columns, alternatively if you know what the names of your columns are, you can pass in something like `names=['col1','col2','col3']`